# Laravel 5.1 refresh and seed a single table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, seeding

I'm looking to refresh and seed a single table in Laravel 5.1. Is this even possible?

I have tried the below, but it gives an error (incorrect syntax).

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=database/migrations/CreateTableTimesheet
```

If I use: `php artisan migrate:refresh` it just says:

> Nothing to migrate

Comment: could you find any solution?

Answer (score 38):

You could use `migrate:refresh` command that will roll back all of your migrations and then execute the `migrate` command. This command effectively re-creates your entire database :

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

And you may use the `--class` option to specify a specific seeder class to run individually :

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UserTableSeeder
```

The full code will be :

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
php artisan db:seed --class=UserTableSeeder
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 15):

Its better to truncate your same table first and then seed:-

```
public function run()
{
    Table::truncate();
    //seed your table here
}
```

then you can run your same seeder like this:-

```
php artisan db:seed --class=YourSeeder
```

Comment: If you are using Eloquent for a model named Users, it's going to be Users::on()->truncate(); .

Answer (score 4):

Maybe first just backup the database, drop it and check if whole seeding, migrating and refreshing mechanic works. But first dump artisan autoload.

Comment: A great way to get your answer up-voted is to include an example or a link to an example.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any answer so far addresses the question of migrating and seeding a **single** table. So, given the migration file `database/migrations/create_foo_table.php` and the seed file `database/seeds/FooTableSeeder.php`, which contains the `FooTableSeeder` seed class, you can do the following:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=database/migrations/create_foo_table.php
php artisan db:seed --class=FooTableSeeder
```

This will rollback, migrate and seed your Foo table. See: [rolling back migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#rolling-back-migrations) and [running seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding#running-seeders) in the Laravel 5.1 documentation (at the time of writing this, Laravel 7.x is out and the syntax has not changed).

Answer (score 2):

Tips for run migration,roleback,refresh and seeder specific file for Laravel Framework

Migrate

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php
```

Roolback

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php
```

Refresh

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php
```

Seeder

```
php artisan db:seed --class=classNameTableSeeder
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
php artisan tinker
```

```
>>> App\Status::truncate()
```

Will clear the statuses table

So you can do

```
>>> App\{MODEL_CLASS}::truncate()
```

---

I found this quite useful when I don't want to clear all the tables, especially users.

Answer (score 1):

include full table name 
example

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path='database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_table_timesheet.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps:

1. Refresh your specific table:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=database/migrations/00_create_foo_table.php
```

2. Seed tables set in `database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan db:seed
```

**=== Extra information ===**

You can comment the seeders you don't want to use in `DatabaseSeeder.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            FooSeeder::class,
            // BarSeeder::class,
            // UserSeeder::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In this example, only `database/seeds/FooSeeder.php` will be passed.